# Are these claims about Owsley County, KY factual

Tags: united-states, politics, welfare

Facebook is a great source of notable claims.  Another one today is this picture:

[image: Claims about Owsley County, Kentucky]

There seem to be three separate claims in this picture:

- Is Owsley County 99%+ white?
- Is Owsley County 95% republican?
- Does Owsley County have the highest usage of SNAP benefits (and by what measure is that claim even made? per capita?)?

Comment: @ChrisW I thought I had seen that question here, but for some reason it didn't show up.  I will close this one as a duplicate.